# Fill space with widgets on resize

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How to do that the 'label' and the 'text' widgets fill all the space when 'root' is being resized?

I'd like to use the 'grid' method if it's possible.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.resizable(width = True, height = True)
label = Label(root, text = "Text")
label.grid()

text = Text(root)
text.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

It doesn't work when I try to use in a class.

Application.py

```
from tkinter import *
import menu
import workPlace

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, boss = None):
        Frame.__init__(self)

        self.master.title("Title")

        self.master.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.master.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight = 1)
        self.master.resizable(width = True, height = True)

        self.menu = menu.MenuBar(self)
        self.menu.grid(sticky = W)

        self.workPlace = workPlace.WorkPlace(self)
        self.workPlace.grid(sticky = "NEWS")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Application().mainloop()
```

workPlace.py

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.scrolledtext as scr 

class WorkPlace(Frame):
    def __init__(self, boss = None):
        Frame.__init__(self)

        self.scrText = scr.ScrolledText(self)
        self.scrText.grid()

        self.label = Label(self,text = "Label")
        self.label.grid()
```

menu.py

```
from tkinter import *

class MenuBar(Frame):
    def __init__(self, boss = None):
        Frame.__init__(self)

        fileMenu = Menubutton(self, text = 'File')
        fileMenu.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        me1 = Menu(fileMenu)

        fileMenu.configure(menu = me1)

        findMenu = Menubutton(self, text = 'Find')
        findMenu.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        me1 = Menu(findMenu)
        findMenu.configure(menu = me1)

        optionMenu = Menubutton(self, text = 'Option')
        optionMenu.grid(row = 0, column = 2)
        me1 = Menu(optionMenu)

        optionMenu.configure(menu = me1)
```

Comment: I haven't got `menu` or `workPlace` modules on my machine. Where did you get them?

Comment: Thanks for posting your other modules. I think I see the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two steps are required.

1. Call `grid_rowconfigure` and `grid_columnconfigure` to set the weight of each of the grid's rows and columns. Rows and columns with a weight of zero don't stretch at all during a resize. This is the default behavior.
2. When calling `grid` on your widgets, specify the `sticky` parameter so the widgets stretch whenever their row or column stretches.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
#uncomment this line if you want the Label widget to stretch vertically.
#or leave it as is if you only want the Text widget to stretch.
#root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

root.resizable(width = True, height = True)
label = Label(root, text = "Text")
label.grid(sticky="NEWS")

text = Text(root)
text.grid(sticky="NEWS")
root.mainloop()
```

---

In the specific case of your WorkPlace object, you need to `configure` both the root object and the WorkPlace object, and you need to specify stickiness for the WorkPlace object and its child objects.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.scrolledtext as scr 

class WorkPlace(Frame):
    def __init__(self, boss = None):
        Frame.__init__(self)

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.scrText = scr.ScrolledText(self)
        self.scrText.grid(sticky="NEWS")

        self.label = Label(self,text = "Label")
        self.label.grid()
```

Comment: Please edit code into your original post instead of pasting it in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

If you are okay with using `pack` instead of `grid`, you can do

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.resizable(width = True, height = True)
label = Label(root, text = "Text")
label.pack(fill=X)
text = Text(root)
text.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```